# __Headers in .htaccess-file to secure website__

Tags: .htaccess, http, header, x-frame-options

I wish you all a good day and a nice start in the Weekend :)

I set the next Headers in htaccess-file:

```
# Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   

 -  Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
 -  Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
 -  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
 -  Header set X-Frame-Options "deny"
 -  Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
 -  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
 -  # Header set Content-Security-Policy ...
 -  Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
 -  Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
</IfModule>
```

but when i scan my Website on "securityheader" it shows all the headers in red color. It means the website is not secure.

I would be so thankful, if someone likes/can show me the error?

Thank you and
Best regards

Comment: Maybe `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` is not true to begin with?

Comment: Hello @CBroe, thank you so much for your answer. Even without the if-statement the scanner shows all the headers in red color. Is there another Website to scan?

Comment: Any body's there? ^^

Comment: What exactly is this “scanner” highlighting in red? What headers are being set?

Comment: Hello @MrWhite, thank you for your support. The "securityheaders dot com" highlighted in red the next "headers" red: "Strict-Transport-Security", "Content-Security-Policy", "X-Frame-Options", "X-Content-Type-Options", "Referrer-Policy" and  "Permissions-Policy". In the browsers DevTool, i can see some headers are set, but the securityheader-plattform-Scanner highlighted (all ! ) headers in red. I already used value for headers of aonther website, which are green to see on the securityheaders-scanner, but they do not work on my site.

Comment: Hello Guys, I wondered, why could so far not get any solution for my issue on this Plattform of genius people and I think I know why. You can confirm or deny it: my website is a subdomain and not a primary domain (Example: 'mywebsite.primarydomain.com'). And this could be exactly the problem, why the HTTP headers don't work. Yesterday I hosted my website by another Host. And the surprise, after scanning the website using securityheaders-plattform was, it highlighted green the header "X-Content-Type-Options". Then i deleted the htaccess-file and it's always green.

Comment: Now to my question please: is it possible to set Headers in a subdomain or do we have to do that in primary main?

Answer (score 0):

As so far nobody mentioned it, you have to remove the *dashes* before each header!

I can recommend [Immuniweb](https://www.immuniweb.com/websec/) for testing the sites security. It will tell you which header is not strict enough, which are outdated and how to improve.
Too many configs in the `.htaccess` reduce the sites speed, so if anything of the headers is outdated comment it below.

```xml
# Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
    Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    # Header set Content-Security-Policy ...
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
    Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
</IfModule>
```

*or with the up2date headers:*

```xml
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
      Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
      Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
      Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
      Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
      Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
      Header set Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=()‚ autoplay=(self), camera=(), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=(), geolocation=(self), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), picture-in-picture=(self), usb=(), interest-cohort=()"
      Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-src 'self'; worker-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri /security-report.php"
</IfModule>
```